# Check if I got JSON from file, how?

Tags: json, asp-classic

In classic ASP I use aspjson library (http://www.aspjson.com/).

I have this code:

```vb
Set objXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objXmlHttp.open "GET", "http://www.xxx.xx/json/fetch.php"), False
objXmlHttp.Send

Set mJSON = New aspJSON
mJSON.loadJSON(objXmlHttp.responseText)
set objXmlHttp = nothing
```

How do I check if the file exists at all and that the file is JSON? Now if the file is not a proper JSON I get error, I'd like to sanity check without error.

Comment: Just use `On Error Resume Next` before the `mJSON.loadJSON()` and after check `If Err.Number <> 0 Then` to capture the error, then return back to `On Error Goto 0` after handling the error.

Comment: Out of interest what is the error you receive, there are only two `Err.Raise()` statements in that entire library one for `No data to load` and another for `Not a collection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the built in error handling `On Error Resume Next` to capture the error in the `Err` object and skip the statement that triggered the error. If an error is generated `Err.Number` will not equal `0`. Once you have checked for the error use `On Error Goto 0` to reset the error handling.

```vb
Set objXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objXmlHttp.open "GET", "http://www.xxx.xx/json/fetch.php"), False
objXmlHttp.Send

Set mJSON = New aspJSON
On Error Resume Next
mJSON.loadJSON(objXmlHttp.responseText)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  'Trap error / do something
  Select Case Err.Number
  Case 1 'No data to load
    'Do something here to handle the error
  Case 2 'Not a collection
    'Do something here to handle the error
  Case Else
    'Unknown error so output it
    Call Response.Write "Unknown Error: " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Source & ") - " & Err.Description
  End Select
End If
On Error Goto 0
Set objXmlHttp = Nothing
```

Comment: This works if the link is not ok and if the JSON file is not ok?

Comment: @Jerry2 Not sure what you mean this just captures any error that is generated by `mJSON.loadJSON()` and allows you to handle it, depending on what error code is return you can handle the error differently just use a `Select Case Err.Number` to check each `Err.Number` you want to handle differently. I'll update my answer...

Comment: Thanx! I would like to find out if the mJson is valid and becomes object or not. I tried using if isObject(mJson) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Seems I need to know what kind of error does every error produce? Problem is loadJSON works even if there is no JSON file, but the for each item in mJSON... produces error and says item is not in collection.

Comment: @Jerry2 Use the same technique to handle those errors and continue as appropriate.

Comment: My problem is that the LoadJSON doesn't produce errors but then the statement: For Each meni In mJson.data("xxx") produces error in meni (not an object). That happens if the URL is working and the file doen't have proper JSON structure.

Comment: Understood @Jerry2, but as I said before you can use the same technique `On Error Resume Next` before the statement triggering the error (in your case inside the `For Each` loop) to bypass it and pass the error tot he `Err` object then check `If Err.Number <> 0 Then` after it and handle the error(s), then `On Error Goto 0` to break out of error handling. Good luck.